# Why is "?5ebb10" added to the end of my URLs?

Tags: css, wordpress

If you visit [this link](http://gtmetrix.com/reports/www.theonewhogetsit.com/ieK4DIy3) and click "Remove query strings from static resources," you'll see a lot of my wordpress files have "?5ebb10" added to the end of the URLs.

I tried disabling my plugins one by one but it doesn't seem to help.

Comment: It's commonly done to avoid caching.  It doesn't make sense for most of those urls, though.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. GTmetrix is giving an F grade because of that. Do you think removing it will speed up my website?

Comment: Nope.  As long as the server's set up correctly (which it is for your site) it's not a problem.  You want to check the network tab and see if you're getting a lot of 200 responses (download this) compared to 304 responses (use cache).  I'm seeing 304 for most things, so you're fine.

Comment: Your site is slow, though.  To speed it up, you want to merge all of those JavaScript files into one file, and do the same for your CSS.  I have to download 15 style sheets and 36 JavaScript files.  You can bring that down to a total of 2 requests.  Expect a very good performance increase from this, both on the client, and strain on your server (less likely to slow on heavy load).  Look into image sprite sheets, to further improve your load time.  Also, move all scripts to just before the end of the body tag.

Comment: Could I use this site to merge the JS files?

http://jscompress.com/

Comment: Yes, that looks good.  [csscompressor.com](http://www.csscompressor.com/) will let you compress the CSS too.

Comment: I missed your last comment. Thanks!